# Copy COM object by Value in .NET

Tags: .net, com

I have a project which references few com objects in a list (for each). I need to copy one object within the loop and compare it with the second one in iteration.
I'm not sure how to copy a com object by value. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot see the internal state of a COM object because you only have an interface to it.

You are limited to any property getters and putters that the COM interface may expose.

For some objects, getting every property you can, and calling the matching `put_` function may be sufficient.  On some, it may not be.

Some interfaces exist for serialization or persistence, and you can use those to store an object, then resurrect a copy of it.

Some COM interfaces may expose a `->Clone()` method.  But that is rare.

In short, there is no reliable way to clone any generic COM object.  The COM object must support duplication in some fashion

Comment: Actually, there might be a reliable way, if the COM object supports [COM persistence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28470998/1768303).

Answer (score 2):

Check if your COM object supports [`IPersistStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or, ideally, `IPersistStreamInit`. This would allow you to save the COM object state into a COM stream (`System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream`).

You could use `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` API to create an in-memory COM stream, then create a new COM object and restore its state from the stream. Essentially, you'd have a cloned object.

There're other COM persistence interfaces (`IPersistFile`, `IPersistMoniker`), but they'd be a bit more difficult to use.